# facebook connect with grails spring security rest plugin

Tags: facebook, rest, grails, grails-plugin, spring-security-rest

Seems like facebook has changed the response format of api call now my code is not working as it suppose to be. I've followed exact same steps to configure plugin mention @ [plugin docs](http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/latest/docs/index.html#_facebook)

I'm facing exact same issue mentioned in [grails-spring-security-rest/issues/327](https://github.com/alvarosanchez/grails-spring-security-rest/issues/327)

**Any workaround/hints to get facebook connect work with grails-spring-security-rest plugin?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/alvarosanchez/grails-spring-security-rest/issues/327#issuecomment-296610128

Someone has posted a workaround.